# Is using try/finally a good practice for memory management?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, try-finally

One of my senior told me to use `try/ finally` block for all the methods to clear the initialized objects data. 
for eg:

```
var serviceProxy = new NotificationServiceProxy();
try
{
     return serviceProxy.GetNotifications(userID, request.Filters, request.FilterProperty, usertypeid);
}
finally
{
     serviceProxy = null;
}
```

Is that a good practice? if i'm using `try/ catch` for all my methods to clear the initialized objects data.

Comment: It's not necessary to clear variables like this. They will be garbage collected once they leave the scope (or even sooner if it's possible).

Comment: It depends on the type of variables you want to clear. Values types- No need. Reference types- Yes you can

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: That is incorrect. If you set the variable of the reference type to `null` you will just dereference it. It will still stay on the heap until it's collected. And if you don't set it to null it will be dereferenced on method exit (and still remain on the heap).

Comment: @Sefe Some of the COM objects or network objects I am mean. Do we not release them gracefully instead of depending on the GC?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: If you need to release objects, you need to dispose them. Nulling the reference does nothing towards releasing anything. It just dereferences, not more and not less.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh COM, Network or anything unmanaged means that you _must_ use the dispose pattern with a finaliser. This `try-finally` is the wrong way to clean that pattern up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in C#, use `using` instead:

```
using(var serviceProxy = new NotificationServiceProxy()){
    serviceProxy.GetNotifications(userID, request.Filters, request.FilterProperty, usertypeid);
    // Do stuff with the service proxy
}

// serviceProxy has now been cleaned up
```

This is the pattern to ensure that `IDisposable` variable get cleaned up.

For instances that aren't disposable this isn't needed - just let them pass out of scope and leave it to the GC.

If `NotificationServiceProxy` uses lots of resources and you need to be sure that it is finalised correctly then make it disposable and always wrap it in a `using` or in another class that also implements `IDisposable`. If it doesn't then this `try-finally` pattern is a waste of time.

Comment: I guess using block can be only used with objects implementing IDisposable interface.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh yes. Either the instance is `IDisposable` and should be wrapped in a `using`, or it isn't and `try-finally` does nothing.

Comment: Is that enough only inheriting the `IDisposable` interface to the `NotificationServiceProxy` class ?

Comment: @King_Fisher if you're only dealing with .NET `IDisposable` objects then yes. If you have unmanaged resources (such as COM+ components) then you also need a `~Finaliser` - Visual Studio will automatically create the method stubs for you. More https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It says `'NotificationServiceProxy' does not implement interface member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'` So i have added  public void Dispose()
        {
             GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }   , should i have to add piece code with in the Dispose method ?

Comment: @King_Fisher if `NotificationServiceProxy` needs to clean up resources it should do so by implementing `IDisposable` and by cleaning them up in `Dispose()`. You only need `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` if you're using the expensive `~Finaliser` pattern, and you only need that if you're dealing with non-.NET resources. If `NotificationServiceProxy` doesn't hold on to resources that you need to clean up then don't implement `IDisposable` and don't bother with `try { } finally { localVar = null; }` as it does nothing.

Comment: I have read in codeproject that, there is no use of calling `dispose` if `NotificationServiceProxy` does not hold non .net resources like db connection, network connection, files on drive and so on. SO I dont need to use using block for all my classes , right ? @Keith

Comment: @King_Fisher If your `NotificationServiceProxy` has any `IDisposable` class variables or properties then it should be disposable too in order to clean them up.
If `NotificationServiceProxy` has unmanaged resources then you need a `~Finaliser` too.
If it doesn't hold on to anything (i.e. every `IDisposable` resource is called in a `using` or `try-finally` block inside a method) then it doesn't need to be disposable itself.

Answer (score 3):

No that's **not** a good practice.

- You are doing work manually, the compiler/garbage collector will do for you. This is unnecessary time spent and unnecessary code clutter you need to remove or maintain later.
- You completely missed to `.Dispose()` the service reference. Although this *could* be done in a `finally` block, the `using` block exists exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to clear a local variable. Before you exit the method, the stack will be reverted anyway (which will free up the space on the stack used by the variable) and setting the local variable to `null` will not free up space on the heap (the garbage collector will do that). Use `try finally` if you need to do some cleanup, for example object disposal or closing files.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a good practice or not, it depends on the scenarios. It's often good to catch the exception so that you can handle unexpected cases gracefully. If your program has developed some other ways to handle exception cases then Try/Finally block should be suffice since Catch block have some performance penalties.

Please review the [Consideration When Using Try Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx#Anchor_5) article from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have no need to clear the local variables (Garbage Collector will do it for you), however, it's safe:

```
 Object o = new Object(); 
 ...
 o = null; // safe, but not required
```

What you have to do is to clear *unmanaged resources*; typical way for this is implementing `IDisposable` interface and wrapping corresponding instances into `using`:

```
 // Providing that serviceProxy implements IDisposable
 using (var serviceProxy = new NotificationServiceProxy()) {
   return serviceProxy.GetNotifications(
     userID, 
     request.Filters, 
     request.FilterProperty, 
     usertypeid);
 } // <- here .Net will call serviceProxy.Dispose() and free the resources allocated
```

sometime you have to *restore the initial state*, and that is the case `try..finally` has been designed for:

```
  Cursor savedCursor = Cursor.Current;

  try {
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    ... 
  }
  finally {
    // Rain (exception thrown) or shine (no exception), please, restore my cursor
    Cursor.Current = savedCursor;
  }
```

In your particular case, I can't see any state to restore, that's why `try..finally` is not the pattern that should be used. However, it's quite possible that `serviceProxy` allocates some *unmanaged resources* (say, TCP/IP port, connection or alike) so it seems that you should implement `IDisposable` for `NotificationServiceProxy` class (if it's not imlemented yet) and wrap the instance into `using`.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense when you need something that **HAS** to happen like Disposing IDisposable objects whether your operation has failed or succeeded.

```
try
{
    myDisposable.Do();
}
finally
{
    myDisposable.Dispose(); 
}
```

you have a built in mechanism which does exactly that :  **Using**

```
using(IDisposable myDisposable = new Something())
{
    myDisposable.Do();
}
```

**Now has to good practice :**

That's kinda up to your error handling strategy and cleanup needs :

- If i have something that **HAS** to be done whether the operation succeed or failed i would put a try finally block.
- if i have something that only need error handling and no cleanup i would place try catch without a finally block
- If i have to do some kind of error handling i would also place a catch block in there
- If i wan't to make some error handling there like a log and then have the Exception propagate from that stack i would also re throw the exception.

*or any permutation of the above conditions ..*

For instance :

```
 try
 {
     myDisposable.Do();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     Log("Error at something something",e); 
     throw e;
 }
 finally
 {
     myDisposable.Dispose(); 
 }
```

I for one do not place try catch finally every where, i want the places in my code that which do contain them stand out stating that these are operations that are known to go wrong for some known reason.

i would welcome new exceptions i'm not yet aware of and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score -7):

Yes, if you need to dispose a variables.